# How to match all letters in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Im have a Helper wich mask some strings and then save it as a xml on a  request/response logger. It was working ok when i was testing in my enviroment, but when other clients start to test i have some issues because of the namespace of the XML. Heres my Regex:

```
formatedString = Regex.Replace( formatedString , "<c.HeresMyString>[0-14]+([0-14]{8})</c.HeresMyString>" , "<c.HeresMyString>****************$1</c.HeresMyString>" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

The problem is that if the clients change the namespace of the tag will change too. So instead of `<c.HeresMyString>` and `</c.HeresMyString>` i need to match eveything. something like `<**HeresMyString>` and `</**HeresMyString>`.

EDIT:
 The examples worked. But i want to replace just the content of the xml tag, this part exactly `[0-14]+([0-14]{8})`. The tag part i want to keep the same as the original string, and not substitute to my namespace.

How can i do that?

Comment: you can split with dot and do a string compare.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
formatedString = Regex.Replace( formatedString , "<[^<>]*HeresMyString>[0-14]+([0-14]{8})</[^\/]*HeresMyString>" , "<c.HeresMyString>****************$1</b.HeresMyString>" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

Comment: I think OP *thinks* they want "something like this" but really needs something altogether different. Typical XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Treating XML and/or HTML with regular expressions is an inherently broken design. This fix might give you a little more mileage, but it's more or less impossible to anticipate how it will break in the future, so is (at best) a brittle solution.

Use the [XML tools available in the platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build an XML document ***properly*** and avoid this sort of nonsense.

Comment: i think you are right. Because ill need to get the incoming namespace and put it on the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but if you just want that to work for any namespace in the original string, use the `.+` pattern for your namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;       

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Your string
        var formatedString = "<newNameSpace.HeresMyString>100000000000</newNameSpace.HeresMyString>";
        formatedString = Regex.Replace( formatedString , "<.+HeresMyString>[0-14]+([0-14]{8})</.+HeresMyString>" , "<b.HeresMyString>****************$1</b.HeresMyString>" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );


        Console.WriteLine(formatedString);
    }
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R8yWM5) and a simple reference on regular expressions http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: thanks, it worked. But ive made an edit in the OP explaining something more. I would like to keep the tag part of the original string. I mean, not substitute with `<b`